# How to generate only half of all binary combinations (MATLAB R2015b)

Tags: matlab, combinations

I am using the following code to generate all binary combinations **M** of length **n_t**.

source: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/164002

```
function M = all_poss(n_t)

% algorithm: recursion 
% remarks: slow for n_t>22

 if n_t > 1 
     L = all_poss(n_t - 1);
     row = size(L,1);
     M = [zeros(row,1) L; ones(row,1) L];  
 else
     M = [0;1];  
 end
```

This code is painfully slow for n_t>20.

Since binary combinations for a given length can be paired e.g

```
[0 0 0] [1 1 1]
[0 0 1] [1 1 0]
[0 1 0] [1 0 1]
[0 1 1] [1 0 0],
```

one way to achieve efficiency is to generate only half of these and get the other half by taking compliment.

I was wondering how can I modify the above code so that it generates only half of the binary combinations or am I supposed to write whole new code for this purpose?

Comment: Why do you need to print out 2^20 binary numbers when you can generate them on the fly with a decimal to binary function?

Comment: What beaker meant in code: `all_poss = @(x)dec2bin(1:(2^x-1))=='1';
`

Comment: Yes that can be done but its not efficient. Takes forever

Comment: Generating 2^20 binary numbers takes a long time. Again, why do you need *all* of the numbers at once? What I was suggesting that you only generate *one* combination when you need it, not generate 2^20 combinations and store them.

Comment: this looks like a viable option. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: not sure where/how this is being implemented but if feasable I would use a look up table with all binary combinations of length n_t up to some max n_t.

Comment: @BradDay That's what the original code generates, a look-up table.

Answer (score -1):

```
function M = all_poss_half(n_t)

n=1;
M = [0;1];
while n<n_t           
    N = cat(2,zeros(size(M,1),1),M);    
    M = cat(1,N,flipud(1-N));  %flipud(.) is not essential here. 
    n=n+1;        
end
```

Comment: Could you please explain your solution?

Comment: Did you try running it? It generates all possible binary combinations M by concatenating N and its compliment 1-N.

Comment: No, I haven't. Nevertheless, it would be nice if you would explain your solution idea, then users who have similar problems will benefit from it.